# Send HTTP Request and "pretending" to be chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser, request, http-headers

How do websites know whether a user is a robot or a human?

Is there any way i can successfully pretend to be chrome without using Headless chrome?

I tried copying Chrome's request headers yet the website still knows i'm a robot but when i use headless chrome it doesn't.

Comment: Enormous number of potential ways.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the website, there are lots of clever ways websites can test for this some off the top of my head are:

- User Agent
- Running Javascript
- Browser FIngerprinting
- Validating that resources that are shown on the page have been loaded
- Some websites use "honeypot" links to detect and block web crawlers and bots

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: OP is probably attempting to break terms of service somewhere.